# Oracle PL/SQL Sequence not incrementing as expected with object constructors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Thanks all in advance. I am having issues with a PL/SQL sequence that is built into object constructors that is not incrementing as expected.

This is the sequence creation.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE base_t_s
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

I then increment it inside object constructors. Base_t object is the super and all others are child object of base_t.

base_t constructor

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION base_t RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        self.oid := base_t_s.NEXTVAL;   -- Create oid using the base_t_s sequence.
        self.name := 'BASE_T';      -- Name the oname as the object type.
        self.oname := 'BASE_T';
        RETURN;
    END base_t;
```

hobbit constructor

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION hobbit ( a_name VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
/* Assign a sequence value and string literal to the instance. */ 
        self.oid := base_t_s.NEXTVAL;
        self.oname := 'HOBBIT';
        self.genus := 'HOBBITS';
/* Assign a parameter to the subtype only attribute. */
        self.name := a_name;
        RETURN;
    END;
```

I create a few hobbits and I get the first increment of 3, then each increment afterwards is by 16. This example is with dwarfs but it is the exact same for each object.

This is the output. I only created these objects in the order they are in.

```
DWARF(3, 'Thorin Oakenshield', 'DWARF', 'DWARVES')
DWARF(19, 'Thorin Oakenshield', 'DWARF', 'DWARVES')
DWARF(35, 'Thorin Oakenshield', 'DWARF', 'DWARVES')
DWARF(51, 'Thorin Oakenshield', 'DWARF', 'DWARVES')
```

I drop the sequence before each run. I have tried only placing the base_t_s.NEXTVAL in the base_t constructor but that did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Note the sequencing is unpredictable due to constructor calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle sequences are not meant for producing contiguous (increment by one) ids in the target table. This is because they are designed to be very fast and to allow multi-threaded access, which means that under the hood, sequence ids are cached in different transactions.

You might be able to alleviate the problem by declaring the sequence with `NOCACHE`, but still there is no guarantee that ids are not skipped if for some reason a transaction were to rollback.

As always, Tom Kyte [explains this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:369390500346406705) in depth.

Comment: I tried `NOCACHE` without success. Thank you for the information about sequence not being reliable. It will be good to know in the future. Thanks for linking the blog. I will have to study it.

Comment: @VERNSTOKED, sequences are extremely reliable, as long as you only rely on them doing what they are supposed to do (generate unique values).

Comment: I will need to continue debugging my code. I do not perform any TCL statements so I can't help but think they should be acting normally.

Comment: After some debugging it turns out you were right. The sequence jumps all over the place due to the constructor calls. Thanks for all the feedback.