# getLastJobExecution in JdbcJobExecutionDao of spring batch returns incorrect last job execution in case of Oracle

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Oracle sequences to generate the unique ids for job executions and other spring batch metadata tables. Oracle uses [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29462523) for sequences because of which the ids are not necessarily in a sequence or increasing order (it only guarantees uniqueness).

In the application, I need to get the last job instance and its last job execution for a feature for which I use the SimpleJobExplorer's getLastJobExecution which calls the JdbcJobExecutionDaos getLastJobExecution method.

The problem is that the query in the getLastJobExecution simply gets the job execution with the max execution id as the last job execution. Because of the way the sequences work in Oracle it returns the incorrect job execution.

Questions :

1. Why does Spring batch use the execution id and not the Start time or the end time to get the last job execution? Am I missing some case here?
2. Is there by chance some API already available in Spring batch to get the last job execution or the last job instance based on the start time or endtime or do I have to implement it on my own?

Comment: @mahmoud-ben-hassine can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2000.

You need to order your sequences as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCYCLE ORDER;
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCYCLE ORDER;
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_SEQ START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCYCLE ORDER;
```

We are considering adding this by default to the provided [DDL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql) for Oracle in v5.

Comment: Why can't we use Start time to determine the last job execution. Using Order btw is not a good idea in Oracle (dba-oracle.com/t_rac_tuning_sequence_order_parameter.htm). For now, I am using my own implementation for getting the last execution using the start time

Comment: Hi Mahmoud can you please have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71602570/spring-batch-batch-job-execution-params-primary-key