# Spring batch batch_job_execution_params primary key

Tags: spring-batch

We are using Spring Batch in our project. In prod Oracle golden gate feature gives the following exception for the batch_job_execution_params table saying :

```
ORA-26970: table "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS'" does not contain a primary key constraint
```

Why does this table not contain a primary key?
I don't think a singular column in this table can be made a primary key however can we have a composite primary key e.g. using the columns JOB_EXECUTION_ID & KEY_NAME? Will that effect the batch jobs in any way?

Comment: @mahmoud-ben-hassine Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Job parameters are seen as value objects and not entities with a given ID: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4e357097bb7c0426b686dc6c2faa4a74200e10bc/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.java#L32. What prevents you from creating a table without a primary key?

Comment: Golder gate replication of Oracle needs to have primary keys in tables for the correct replication else it gives the error I have mentioned. Would it create problems if we make the job_exection_id and key name as a primary key?

Comment: In that case, you need to add a combination of columns that is guaranteed to be unique as a primary key for that table.